# Why is IPv6 ping failing to access google.com?

Tags: windows, ping, ipv6, traceroute

I have found that ping google.com from my Windows 7 box has stopped working.

Below is the output - note that the IPv4 ping works, and Yahoo works. Is my local router at fault here?

```
C:\Users\Jeff>ping google.com

Pinging google.com [2001:4860:4007:801::1007] with 32 bytes of data:
Destination net unreachable.
Destination net unreachable.
Destination net unreachable.
Destination net unreachable.

Ping statistics for 2001:4860:4007:801::1007:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

C:\Users\Jeff>ping -4 google.com

Pinging google.com [74.125.224.206] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 74.125.224.206: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=55
Reply from 74.125.224.206: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=55

Ping statistics for 74.125.224.206:
    Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 5ms, Maximum = 5ms, Average = 5ms
Control-C
^C
C:\Users\Jeff>ping yahoo.com

Pinging yahoo.com [98.139.183.24] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 98.139.183.24: bytes=32 time=98ms TTL=46
Reply from 98.139.183.24: bytes=32 time=86ms TTL=46

Ping statistics for 98.139.183.24:
    Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 86ms, Maximum = 98ms, Average = 92ms
Control-C

C:\Users\Jeff>ping -6 google.com

Pinging google.com [2001:4860:4007:801::1005] with 32 bytes of data:
Destination net unreachable.
Destination net unreachable.
Destination net unreachable.

C:\Users\Jeff>tracert google.com

Tracing route to google.com [2001:4860:4007:801::1008]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1  Destination net unreachable.

Trace complete.
```

Comment: Can you route other IPv6 traffic? Or is it just v6 ping that is failing?

Comment: It seems that the route to 2001:4860:4007:801::1005 is broken somewhere... Can you show a traceroute to that address?

Comment: Thanks - Added tracert to google.com, not much info there. Perhaps the local router here does not support IPv6. How would I know if other IPv6 traffic was working properly? I suppose I could disable IPv4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your PC thinks it has IPv6 connectivity, but that your local router doesn't properly work. Did you configure IPv6 addresses on the network interface manually? In that case you should probably remove that fixed configuration. The rest depends on how your ISP provides IPv6 to you, and on if/how your router handles it.

Comment: Agree with your conclusions. We are looking at the router/ISP now. It's interesting that on some networks, my laptop will default to IPv4 (and I can override to IPv6 - which will work), while other networks is the opposite. Interesting times ahead!

Comment: More info much later now. Turned out ATT (our ISP) did not support IPv6 yet. We turned off IPv6 for now -